# Read nested data from json using .proto in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I want to read nested data from a json. I have created a .proto file based on the json but still I am not able to read nested data from this said json.

`nested.proto` --> compiling using `protoc --python_out=$PWD nested.proto`

```
syntax = "proto2";


message Employee{
    required int32 EMPLOYEE_ID = 1;
    
    message ListItems {
        required string FULLADDRESS = 1;
    }

    repeated ListItems EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = 2;

}
```

`nested.json`

```
{
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5044,
    "EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS": [
        {
            "FULLADDRESS": "Suite 762"
        }
    ]
}
```

`parse.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse

import nested_pb2 as np


input_file = "nested.json"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # reading json file
    f = open(input_file, 'rb')
    content = json.load(f)
    # initialize emp_table here
    emp_table = np.Employee()

    employee = Parse(json.dumps(content), emp_table, True)
    print(employee.EMPLOYEE_ID) #output: 5044
    
    
    emp_table = np.Employee().ListItems()
    
    
    items = Parse(json.dumps(content), emp_table, True)
    
    print(items.FULLADDRESS) #output: NO OUTPUT (WHY?)
```

Comment: Sorry, what’s the use case for proto here? how would deserializing json alone not solve the problem for example?

Comment: Think of it as running a select sql query on json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. The type is `ListItems` but the name is `EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS`
2. Python is awkward (!) with `repeated`'s
3. You're writing more code than you need
4. I recommend adhering to the [style guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style) if you can.

Try:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse

import nested_pb2 as np

input_file = "nested.json"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # reading json file
    f = open(input_file, 'rb')
    content = json.load(f)
    # initialize emp_table here
    emp_table = np.Employee()

    employee = Parse(json.dumps(content), emp_table, True)
    print(employee.EMPLOYEE_ID) #output: 5044

    for item in employee.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS:
        print(item)
```

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it. If it helped, please consider marking this as the answer, thanks.